# .gitlab-ci.yml cannot resolve a cdcd variable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

In gitlab I set a custom variable:
Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables -> Add variable

[image: screenshot]

Then I try to access it inside my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
  stage: Deploy
  script:
    - echo $LOL_KEK_VAR
    - echo %LOL_KEK_VAR%
    - echo "$env:LOL_KEK_VAR"
```

But the variable is not resolved here is the output:

```
$ echo $LOL_KEK_VAR
$ echo %LOL_KEK_VAR%
%LOL_KEK_VAR%
$ echo "$env:LOL_KEK_VAR"
:LOL_KEK_VAR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: From your screenshot it's looking like your variable is protected. Is your pipeline running on a protected branch/tag?